# AForge.NET/Accord.NET Snapshot Maker never connects to back camera for Panasonic FZ-G1 tablet

Tags: c#, camera, aforge, accord.net

I'm trying to use the Snapshot Maker sample from the AForge.NET project and on my laptop, it works as intended.  There is only one camera ("Integrated Camera") that shows up in the dropdown.  However, when I move this executable to a Panasonic FZ-G1 tablet, the dropdown contains an entry for "USB HD Webcam" (front) and "USB2.0 Camera" (back).  When I connect to the front camera, the video preview starts within a second.  However, when I attempt to connect to the other camera, the AForge control never stops displaying "connecting..."

I've subscribed to all the events I found in an attempt to see if there are errors occurring, but I can't seem to capture anything going wrong.  I also had it display whether it `IsRunning` which returns `true`.  I've checked Windows Event Viewer for anything displayed there and nothing shows up.

Is there anything else I can do to diagnose the connection issues?  I need a video preview/high-resolution snapshot capability using the camera on the back for these tablets and I've had no luck with just DirectShow and AForge.NET seemed to be a great alternative to try.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

### Update

I've since found out that AForge.NET "has become" Accord.NET.  The source code moved over to this repo and has been worked on since.  However, the same issue still persists.

Comment: This might have been fixed in release 3.8.0. If it still doesn't work for you, please consider [opening an issue at the project's issue tracker](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/).